# How to check whether an image is part of an larger image

Tags: php, image, algorithm, webserver, compare

I am looking for an algorithm to compare two images, one is given static in highest quality and the other is taken individually with maybe not so good quality periodically.

The static one is way smaller and should be IN the second image at different positions.

Is there an algorithm to compare whether an image is part of another image like i described and the result is maybe given as odds to be in there?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the small image does not change in the bigger images (just the position changes) then all you need is a fuzzy comparison function between two small squares of pixels in two images that compare the positions of colors and give a match score (You could even just use sum-of-squared distance in RGB space). If the small image is higher resolution than the larger images then you'll have to scale the pixel widths of the squares you are comparing accordingly, and possibly use fractional pixels to make sure the actual sizes of the square patches you are comparing are equal.

Anyway, once you get a strong enough match for a small square then you can continue to compare the rest of the squares in the images to verify that you have a match. Just keep going as long as the match score between squares is high enough, and as soon as it isn't, then move on to the next possible position for the small image inside the larger image. For images with a lot of entropy everywhere (not a lot of plain black spots, for example) this should work very fast.